# How to add collisions in Unity with character controller?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a Unity game and I was having some trouble with it.

I created the movement of my character watching a tutorial and implementing the new input system. I now need to implement collisions so my character can shoot at enemies but I can not add a rigid body or a box collider because it uses character controller for the movement. Any ideas on how to resolve this? I tried watching some tutorials but I couldnt solve my problem and as I am new to this, I do not know what else to do.

This is the code I have at the moment for the movement. Controller.Move() is commented because I was having trouble with it but it is what makes my character move:

```
void playerMovement()
    {
        Vector2 inputVector = move.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        finalVector.x = inputVector.x;
        finalVector.y = inputVector.y;

        //Vector3 currentPos = transform.position;
        if (finalVector != Vector3.zero)
        {
            if (move.ReadValue<Vector2>().y == -1)
            {
                Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(180, 0, 0);
                transform.rotation = target;
                //controller.Move(finalVector * Time.deltaTime * speed);
                
            }
            else
            {
                if (move.ReadValue<Vector2>().y == 1)
                {
                    Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
                    transform.rotation = target;
                    //controller.Move(finalVector * Time.deltaTime * speed);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    if (move.ReadValue<Vector2>().x == 1)
                    {
                        Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -90);
                        transform.rotation = target;
                        //controller.Move(finalVector * Time.deltaTime * speed);
                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (move.ReadValue<Vector2>().x == -1)
                        {
                            Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);
                            transform.rotation = target;
                            //controller.Move(finalVector * Time.deltaTime * speed);
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I shoot:

```
void playerShoot() {
        if (!canShoot) return;
        GameObject b = Instantiate(bullet, bulletDirection.position, bulletDirection.rotation);
        bullet.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine(canPlayerShoot());
    }
```

Comment: Why can’t you put a box collider on? You should just be able to do it by setting a child game object with the box collider.

Comment: Simple but effective. Thank you mate

Answer (score 0):

You should add a child game object, and then add the box collider to that. When using `OnCollisionEnter()`, it uses all the collider in child game objects too.